# Get from IQueryable<T> predicate Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, linq, expression, iqueryable, func

I'm trying apply query from one collection to another. 
Sample of my test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Expression sourceExpression = Amazings().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Kasa")).AsQueryable().Expression;

        Expression<Func<Amazing, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Amazing, bool>>(sourceExpression, Expression.Parameter(typeof(Amazing)));

        var col2 = Amazings().Where(predicate.Compile());
    }

    private IEnumerable<Amazing> Amazings()
    {
        var amazings = new List<Amazing>
            {
                new Amazing
                    {
                        Name = "Kasa",
                    },
                new Amazing
                    {
                        Name = "Ma@p2a"
                    }
            };
        return amazings;
    }

    class Amazing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is wrong?
When I run this test in debug I get the exception:

*You can not use expressions such as „System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1+Amazing]” for the return type „System.Boolean”.*

If I run this without parameter I got exception that I don't have parameters.

If I change parameter to boolean type I got exception: you can't use element bool type for delegate parameter type Amazing...

I tested few more options but nothing works.

Also I found that the key may by casting Expression to: MethodCallExpression but it's not or I can't figurate how.

I tried with somothing like this:

```
MethodCallExpression e = query.Expression as MethodCallExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)e.Object;

        Expression<Func<Amazing, bool>> getCallerExpression = Expression<Func<Amazing>>.Lambda<Func<Amazing, bool>>(memberExpression);
```

Unfortunately memberExpression is null.

I searched the web and the only thing I found it's a tip: *~"don't do this"*.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want to do... But as Servy wrote, you put the `AsQueryable()` in the wrong place. The right place is **before** the `.Where()`, and this being a Unit Test, I suggest that the method that returns the data should directly return a `IQueryable<T>`, to better simulate "normal" queries you can find in code.

Try looking if this is what you want...

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var q1 = Amazings().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Kasa"));

    Expression predicate = q1.Expression;

    var q2 = Amazings();
    IQueryable<Amazing> q3 = q2.Provider.CreateQuery<Amazing>(predicate);
}

private IQueryable<Amazing> Amazings()
{
    var amazings = new List<Amazing>
    {
        new Amazing
            {
                Name = "Kasa",
            },
        new Amazing
            {
                Name = "Ma@p2a"
            }
    };
    return amazings.AsQueryable();
}
```

Note that in the most general case, you can't simply move the `Expression<Func<Amazing, bool>>` condition of a `.Where()`, because you could have a `.Where().Select()` or something similar.

Other possible solution, if you know that the last method is a `.Where()` and you **really** want to "move" the `Expression<Func<Amazing, bool>>`:

```
MethodCallExpression mce = predicate as MethodCallExpression;

if (mce == null)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

UnaryExpression quote = mce.Arguments[1] as UnaryExpression;

if (quote == null || quote.NodeType != ExpressionType.Quote)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

Expression<Func<Amazing, bool>> lambda = quote.Operand as Expression<Func<Amazing, bool>>;

if (lambda == null)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

IQueryable<Amazing> q4 = Amazings().Where(lambda);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)
Unfortunately I can't click 'vote up', because I haven't enough points, but it really helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're calling `Enumerable.Where` and not `Queryable.Where` the lambda you have is never translated into an `Expression`, it's only ever compiled into a method, and the `IQueryable` that you have doesn't even have any way of getting to that delegate, because all that *it* sees is an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>`.